# YAML indenting with neovim and treesitter?

Tags: syntax, indentation, neovim, treesitter

I've recently upgraded to neovim 0.5.0, and I've been experimenting at replacing older syntax and indenting plugins with treesitter. I'm having some problems getting things to work correctly when editing YAML files.

I have the following in my `init.lua` file:

```
local ts = require 'nvim-treesitter.configs'
ts.setup {ensure_installed = 'maintained',
    highlight = {
        enable = true,
        additional_vim_regex_highlighting = false,
    },
    indent = {
        enable = true,
        disable = {"python", }
    },
}
```

Running `:checkhealth` reports

```
health#nvim_treesitter#check
========================================================================
[...]
## Parser/Features H L F I J
[...]
  - yaml           ✓ ✓ ✓ ✓ ✓
```

But when I create a YAML file, for example...

```
- hosts: foo<RETURN>
```

...then the cursor ends up at column 0 on the following line, rather
than indented as required. This behaviors persists for the rest of the
file: regardless of the YAML syntax, the cursor always goes to column 0
on return

I know that treesitter indent support is considered "experimental". Is
this just broken right now, or do I have something misconfigured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the YAML parser's indentations are pretty rudimentary: https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter/blob/master/queries/yaml/indents.scm

You may have a better development experience by just disabling tree-sitter indentation for just `yaml` and using the default Vim regex indentation instead.

In your nvim-treesitter config

```
require('nvim-treesitter.configs').setup {
  indent = {
    enable = true,
    disable = { 'yaml' }
  }
}
```